# How to integrate sqlite3 C++ interface

Tags: c++, sqlite, libraries

I'm trying to use SQLite3 for database managing in my little project on Windows, I just made some C++ code to generate my database but I can't link my code with the "sqlite3.h" file, no matter if I use

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
```

compiling with

```
g++ DBconfig.cpp -l sqlite3
```

(in that case the compiling error is "fatal error: sqlite.h: no such file or directory").

I can't either use

```
#include "path/sqlite3.h"
```

Tried compiling in many ways, results in tons of declared but not defined things like the function "sqlite_exec()".

Everywhere people fix this easily by using a linux "sudo" command or downloading and compiling sqlite3 libraries, I tried that, nothing removes these errors. I have SQLite 3 installed, along with its interface (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite) files that I ran with "lib /def:" command.

Internet tutorials say just installing sqlite3, including the first way I did and compiling with "-l sqlite3" should work.

Comment: Unless you need the database engine to be an external library for some reason, the simplest way to use SQLite in a C++ application is to include the `sqlite3.c` amalgamated source file and the `sqlite3.h` header in your application's source tree. The source for the class wrapper likewise.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I didn't know how to compile that so I rewrote everything in C, used your suggestion and it worked. Thanks